# How do Necromorphs grow extra body parts?

Tags: horror, zombie, dead-space

In *Dead Space*, the zombies created by Markers are called Necromorphs. Supposedly, the Marker manipulates cells to turn them into monsters. However, this results in the Necromorphs having long limbs and even claws.

The question is, if Necromorphs are just mutated dead cells, how do they grow an extra pair of longer limbs and extra features, instead of just looking like normal dead people lumbering around?

Comment: If this question can be answered from information in-universe, or from a cast or crew comment out-of-universe, then it is in scope for this site. I was going to write an answer based solely on real-world information not originating in the franchise. (what DNA is, what mutation means, and difference in possibilities between natural and artificial mutation). Unfortunately that kind of answer is out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

## Their biology is a sludge that the markers can alter the shape of broadly as they wish.

See Log:Re-Animate

> Dr. Heidi Latchford Research Summary Organic Material analysis: There are several shocking finds relating to the sludge-like material found throughout the Ishimura. First it is human DNA. Second, and far more disturbing, it re-animates in the presence of a Marker signal. The only conclusion we can come to is that the entire Ishimura crew was infected and "reconstructed", and then fell into a soupy DNA-sludge when the Aegis VII Marker was destroyed.

This sort of sludge is a lot of mutations away from humans. They have a lot of freedom in how they reconstruct humans. I wouldn't assume there's an easy natural evolution path to necromorphs, they're an advanced biotech creation.

Comment: Also, see the extra logs you unlock in the first game after finishing it and loading the cleared save. One of them mention the "legs" aren't actual legs, but more like "tails" that don't have any bone at all or something. More like muscles that work like spring under tension or something.

Comment: https://deadspace.fandom.com/wiki/Recombination_Study Apparently, it was just a description of someone turning into both an Infector and a Leaper

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of mutation on necromorphs. The most common kind, the [Slasher](https://deadspace.fandom.com/wiki/Slasher) uses flesh and bones from the victim's hands and stomach. You can see the original hands of the victim near it's stomach region. Some of them, notably Pukers, has a leg made solely out of intestines and flesh, where the other two legs are fused together. The leaper's tail is also another example of excessive mutation.